# Metricbeat filesystem type ignore seems not work

Tags: elastic-stack, metricbeat

I'm trying to setup disk usage visualization in Kibana using Metricbeat system module. It seems to ignore the `filesystem.ignore_types` setting and feed data of all mounted filesystems, including virtual kernel-related binfmt_misc, cgroup, debugfs, sysfs, proc, devpts, securityfs etc.
My configfile looks as following:

```
metricbeat.modules:

- module: system
  metricsets:
    - cpu
    - load
    - filesystem
    - memory
  filesystem.ignore_types: [binfmt_misc, cgroup, tmpfs, debugfs, sysfs, binfmt_misc, proc, devpts, securityfs, autofs,mqueue,hugetlbfs, fusectl, pstore]
  enabled: true
  period: 60s
```

but still Metricbeat sends data of filesystems of these types to Elasticsearch.

```
2017-09-11T22:56:04+02:00 DBG  Publish: {
  "@timestamp": "2017-09-11T20:56:04.816Z",
  "beat": {
    "hostname": "osboxes",
    "name": "osboxes",
    "version": "5.5.2"
  },
  "metricset": {
    "module": "system",
    "name": "filesystem",
    "rtt": 1456
  },
  "system": {
    "filesystem": {
      "available": 0,
      "device_name": "sysfs",
      "files": 0,
      "free": 0,
      "free_files": 0,
      "mount_point": "/sys",
      "total": 0,
      "used": {
        "bytes": 0,
        "pct": 0.000000
      }
    }
  },
  "type": "metricsets"
}
```

My mounted systems, but I'd like to transfer only "real" ext4 partition:

```
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=1010500k,nr_inodes=209328,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=206136k,mode=755)
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=23,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=12394)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
/dev/sda2 on /boot type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/sda4 on /home type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=206136k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,relatime)
```

Any hint?

Comment: I am facing same issue. Did you get it to work ?

Comment: well, no. The project was declined, and I did not any further investigations.

Comment: `filesystem.ignore_types` was introduced in metricbeat 5.6 and 6.0, it seems that this event was generated with 5.5.2, is it not working in greater versions?